# How do I change the default font size?

Tags: fontsize

How can I change the default font size throughout the LaTeX document? Is this even possible?

Comment: There are two general answers below if you need a more detailed answer improve your question please, and tell us at least which class you are using …

Answer (score 29, accepted):

at least some document classes provide an optional argument to do this.  for example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
```

will provide a changed set of font sizes (`\footnotesize` will be smaller, for example) in a coherent style.

Comment: The `memoir` document class provides an extended range of font sizes (9 to 13 points).

Answer (score 19):

The standard classes have options `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` to load configurations for a main font in the given size and matching sizes for headlines etc.

If your using KOMA-Script use the option `fontsize=<size>` to set a size that may differ from the above three.

To change the size of the main font only try `\fontsize{<size>}{<skip>}\selectfont` but this is not a real user command so one should know what he does when using it ;-)

Comment: It's worth noting that the [extsizes classes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) (extarticle, extreport, etc.) support font sizes from 8pt to 20pt.

Answer (score 15):

You can change the main font size and the other font sizing commands (as long as the font is scalable) through the `fontsize` package.

#### The `fontsize` package option

The most basic way is to use the `fontsize` option which automatically sets the line spacing:

```
\usepackage[fontsize=10.8pt]{fontsize}
```

#### The `\changefontsize` command

If you need precise line spacing you can use the `\changefontsize` command:

```
\usepackage{fontsize}
  \changefontsize[12.8pt]{11pt}
```

Here is a minimal working example. The normal size and the normal line spacing are set to 11pt and 12.75pt respectively:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage{fontsize}
  \changefontsize[12.75]{11}
\begin{document}
 \blinddocument  
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: ![enter image description here]

#### Printing samples

The values ​​of the font sizing commands can be obtained with the `\printsamples` command:

```
\printsamples
```

prints the values of the font size and line spacing for all the sizes defined by the package.

```
\printsamples{12.8pt}{11.2pt}[normalsize,tiny,tinyr,tinyrr,tinyrrr]
```

prints the values of the font size and line spacing for all the sizes declared in the optional argument.

Here is a minimal working example with the Cochineal font:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage{fontsize}
\begin{document}
  \printsamples{12.8pt}{11.2pt}[normalsize,tiny,tinyr,tinyrr,tinyrrr]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]